# How to generate sequence in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

when I execute following query.

select 
     30,60,90,120,150,180 
from 
    table

I get output given below [image]

But my desire output like, Want out in only one column.

```
 sequence 
   30
   60
   90
   120
   150
   180
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `UNION ALL` that will work in all major RDBMSes

```
SELECT 30 "sequence" UNION ALL
SELECT 60 UNION ALL
SELECT 90 UNION ALL
SELECT 120 UNION ALL
SELECT 150 UNION ALL
SELECT 180
```

or use postgres' [`generate_series()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-srf.html) function

```
SELECT * 
  FROM generate_series(30, 180, 30) "sequence";
```

Output:

```
| SEQUENCE |
|----------|
|       30 |
|       60 |
|       90 |
|      120 |
|      150 |
|      180 |
```

Here is **[SQLFIddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/d41d8/1474)** demo for both queries

Comment: I would delete the first version. The second one is the (only) way up go.

Answer (score 1):

A bit shorter than using UNION ALL:

```
select *
from ( values (30), (60), (90), (120), (150), (180) ) as numbers (seq_no);
```

Alternatively:

```
with numbers (seq_num) as (
  values (30), (60), (90), (120), (150), (180)
)
select *
from numbers;
```

Answer (score 1):

As @peterm said, the way to go in PostgreSQL would be to use [generate_series()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-srf.html).

In other RDBMS which support recursive cte, you can use it like this:

```
with recursive cte(sequence) as (
    select 30
    union all
    select sequence + 30
    from cte
    where sequence < 180
)
select *
from cte
```

Also, if your RDMBS supports window functions, and you have some table, and you know there're always exists at least 6 rows in this table, you can do this :)

```
select
    row_number() over(order by id) * 30
from temp
limit 6
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/d41d8/1475)</kbd>**

Answer (score 1):

As other answers mention, generate_series is the way to go when the data you want to generate is a even spaced series like this. If not, I like the version by a_horse_with_no_name. Another way is:

```
select unnest('{30,60,90,120,150,180}'::int[]) as numbers
```